# MySQL - archive table data

Tags: mysql

I would like to learn how I can archive old table data in a separate table automatically.

I have a very big table which grows and grows constantly. The actually relevant data for me is the latest ~1000 rows. All other data is "nice to have" but is irrelevant. So I want to move it to separate location in order to speed up SELECT queries.

Comment: If you want to optimize performance, moving the data off might not be the best solution. What if you need to access the archived data quickly? Have you looked at optimizing the table itself, as well as your query? Do you have some indexes in place? If you do want to archive though, most people set up some sort of scheduled job to do this. Is it on a Unix OS?

Comment: Yup, this is Linux. In regards to "access the archived data quickly" - I don't need it. And if I need it, I will do it manually by browsing the database. This data is not used in the project. This is like some kind of logs, so the old ones are irrelevant because they are too old.

Comment: if you dont need it, back it up and delete it. otherwise, consider partitioning by date. how long does it take to accumulate 1000 rows?

Comment: That's a fair point... Especially if it's not actively used. We do archiving in my job, but it's just to move data off SSD's, and onto hard disks so that the "archived" data is slower, but still in the same table. Anyway, just something to keep in mind, that you could potentially need it someday if you're not willing to just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set up a scheduled job of some sort. There are multiple ways to go about this, but this simplest way (in my opinion) is to set up a [Cron Job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml), since you're on Linux. You can use it to go off every day, or however often you want, and have it kick of a sql script to move the data for you, past your threshold.

You can also supposedly schedule jobs in MySQL, but I've never done this.

This answer is just to answer the conceptual question, but not to provide technical details, since I'm not sure that's what you need. I'm happy to edit my answer to provide a cron example if you need it.

Hopefully that helps!